# Calling GET request with parameters from first HEAD response

Tags: javascript, angular, api, http

In my Angular app I have to call two HTTP request. First request is HEAD which return important parameter in header response (total number of records). Second request is GET and returns all records when HTTP header contains number for total records from header response.

Now I have two methods getHeader() and getData(records: number).

```
this.appService.getHeader().subscribe(
  (response) => {
    const records = response.headers.get('X-Total');

    this.appService.getData(records).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.data = dataFromServer;
      }
    );

  }
);
```

That works pretty well, but I would like to know if exist more elegant solution?

Comment: Which version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: I am using Angular 6 and RxJS 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would obviously be simpler if you modify the backend, so that only one request is required. That said, if it's not an option,you can use `switchMap`, like so:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

//...

this.appService.getHeader().pipe(
    switchMap(resp => this.appService.getData(resp.headers.get('X-Total')))
).subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
});
```